# Is it possible to make Ms Word default new file with personalized header & footer?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

In my `.docx` file, I want to have the company name in header and page number in footer. And this should be auto inserted in my new/blank document.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new template in Microsoft Word...

> [Create Letterhead Template - How to make a letterhead in Microsoft Word](http://www.helpwithpcs.com/courses/create-letterhead-word.html)

The instructions are for Microsoft Word 2003, but you should be able to get the idea...

When you want to write a new document with your customized template, just click the `Office orb` (uppermost left-hand corner) -> `New` -> `My Templates`, and your customized template should be in there.